# Modify the value of each textfield based on original value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is it possible to modify the value of each textfield present in a webpage, based on the original value, using jQuery or JavaScript?

For example, suppose I have 50 textfields in a page. I want to remove whitespace from the beginning and end of each textfield’s value. I don’t find it to be a good idea to call the function for every textfield individually. How can I do it without calling a function for each textfield?

Comment: By textfield do you mean `input type="text"` or `textarea`?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that part clearly..Ya but I was trying for input type ="text" only.

Comment: Without jQuery, it’s just as trivial: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']")).forEach((elem) => elem.value = elem.value.trim());`.

Comment: Some closely related variations: Reaching the current element (and its properties): [How to reach the element itself inside jQuery’s `val`?](/q/16710521/4642212); Mapping the current value (basically the same as this; e.g. via a function, or appending something to it): [Append text to input field](/q/841722/4642212); Using the index of the element in the collection: [Insert array values in inputs with specific class, index by index](/q/58516211/4642212).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can just use `val()` with a callback argument. It will loop over all elements for you:

```
$('input[type=text]').val(function( index, originalValue){
     return $.trim(originalValue);
});
```

**[val() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function)**

Answer (score 0):

Get all the inputs from the page using jquery then run a loop, and for each element trim the value

```
<body>
    <input type="text" value="   abc    " >
    <input type="text" value="   def    " >   
    <input type="button" id="remove" value="Remove">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#remove').click(function(){
                var inputs = $('input[type=text]');
                $.each(inputs, function(index,input){
                    $(input).val($(input).val().trim()) 
                });
            });
        });
    </script>  
</body>
```

Comment: for `input[type=text]` use `input:text`

Comment: Thanks a lot..Stack overflow should also provide option to select multiple answer as correct.

Comment: You are welcome. No, Stack overflow doesn't provide option to select multiple answer as correct. But if you find any answer correct any useful you can give an up vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this code:

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function (i, e) {
    var $this = $(e);
    $this.val($this.val().trim());
});
```

Comment: `e` is the DOM element, and `$(e)` is a JQuery element that I assign a variable named `$this` (not `$(this)`)

Comment: I know, but `$(this)` is already usable as the jQuery object for that dom element within that loop. `$(this) === $(e)`.

Comment: You're right. In this case, using $(this) or $(e) is equivalent. I assign $(e) into a variable to avoid execute the function $(e) (or $(this)) two times.